# Displaying same font size in any Android screen

Tags: android, fonts

I want a text to have relatively same size in every Android device.

I have a canvas (fullscreen). In middle of this canvas is some text. This text fills 20% of my screen leaving 40% for both sides. I want these precentages to be true when text is viewed in any Android device.

I also want the same thing vertically.

Comment: I apply the name size to a paint using paint.setTextSize(size). I have tried to multiply the size with scale of resolution and density change in Android devices. The result seems to end up being from a perfect copy to a bit too big when multiplying with resolution change scale.

Comment: I noticed that result depends on original size more than expected. Size 21 seems to be most accurately the same. Smaller size resulted percentically smaller result and bigger size vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Put the size into a [Dimension resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) using “sp” units.

Comment: Better unit would be dp as it's meant to be exactly the same in every screen and doesn't look at user preferences. I tried this: `setTextSize(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, size, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));` The text did not have the same size on different screens.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to measure width of text in pixels and save that value.

When text is loaded in different resolution, I multiply the original pixels with scale of resolution change. I loop up from text size one, always calculating new resolution and checking which matches the original resolution best.